# Wrong numeration using \newtheorem

Tags: theorems

by using the `\newtheorem`, the latex does not number the theorems in the right order.

used code is

```
\newtheorem{theo.a}{Proposition}
\begin{theo.a}
this is the proposition.
\end{theo.a}
```

changing into

```
\newtheorem{theo.a}{Proposition}[2]
\begin{theo.a}
this is the proposition.
\end{theo.a}
```

leads to a wrong output as well (Proposition 1 is replaced by Proposition .1)

[image: output]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? There is no counter called `2` any ways.

Comment: I try to construct "Proposition 2"

Comment: You are aware that using `theo.a` a second time, it will print `Proposition 2`?!? Numbers are automatic.

Comment: Your are right. I forgot to say, that I don't use them in the right order. (first prop 2, then prop 1) My fault..

Comment: Why, wouldn't that confuse the reader?

Comment: In this certain content it is useful.

Answer (score 2):

Please always post complete small documents, not unusable fragments however like most latex counter constructs,

```
\newtheorem{theo.a}{Proposition}
```

defines `theo.a` to increment the counter before printing it so if you want to start at Proposition 42 then you just need

```
\setcounter{theo.a}{41}
\begin{theo.a}
this is the proposition.
\end{theo.a}
```